# Как динамически генерировать переменную в ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

Нужно динамически менять переменную в `ng-model`. Ниже пример моего кода. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
    <div ng-repeat="i in formCtrl.nmbrEntryField" >
        <textarea type="text" id="formul_{{$index}} active" entry-field 
                  ng-model="formCtrl.formulaVal_{{$index}}" 
                  class="formula formula-active" rows="1" name="formula[]">
        </textarea>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создаете массив объектов в контроллере

   ```
   function ExampleControllerFn() {
       var vm = this;
       vm.items = [
           'one',
           'two',
           'three'
       ];
   }
   ```
2. С помощью директивы `ng-repeat` связываете инпуты с элементами массива

   ```
   <div ng-repeat="item in exampleCtrl.items">
       <textarea cols="30" rows="10" ng-model="item"></textarea>
   </div>
   ```

https://jsfiddle.net/1s7427ue/

Comment: Неверно. Этот код не работает так, как должен. https://jsfiddle.net/1s7427ue/1/

Comment: `g-model="exampleCtrl.items[$index]"` - это сработает https://jsfiddle.net/1s7427ue/2/ Только не пойму, что с фокусом происходит...

Comment: Если кому то будет нужно вот здесь описывается решение проблемы с фокусом и всего вопроса в целому: [http://habrahabr.ru/post/223529/]